# Webservices and Lotus Domino Server in C#

Tags: c#, .net, connection, lotus, groupwise

Hy my Questions is,

for example i connect to MS Exchange Server 2007 - 2013 in .net C#

with the ews managed api 2.0 with simmilar this Connection string:

```
     ...
     service = new ExchangeService(); 
     service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user Email", "Password");
     service.AutodiscoverUrl("user Email");
     ...
```

and how would it look like for a connection to Lotus Notes Domino Server Version 7- 9 and maybe for GroupWise Server ?

Comment: Hey did you found any solution to this? We are trying to do the similar. Need something like exchange server push notifications for domino server. Or at least want to know if we can fetch all the mails in particular folder of mailbox in array of byte buffers.

Answer (score 0):

I found a link that seems to answer your question:

http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2011/09/integrating-a-lotus-notes-application-with-exchange.html